# why does applicationWillTerminate: delegate does not fire on minimize?

Tags: iphone, ios

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
[InAppPurchaseManager closeStore];
[[InAppPurchaseManager sharedDownloadManager] saveReceipts];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"ISPARSERLOCKED"];
}
```

I am working on ios 5 ...i would like to know if there are situations that will not fire the above method on minimize.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By minimize I assume you mean another app becoming the active app. That almost never causes termination in iOS anymore. You may never get `applicationWillTerminate` in iOS. For detecting when you become inactive look at `-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and `-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`, both are app delegate methods.

Comment: Not really...i mean pressing the home button or removing the app from the minimized app list by double clicking the home button and closing the app there.

Comment: Pressing the home button just makes Springboard the active app. It does not terminate the current app (on any device running iOS 4 or newer except those that don't support multitasking). Honestly, I don't know what happens if you force quit the app. You might get applicationWillTerminate but I'm not sure that's guaranteed.